# How do I move a rock?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

More than once I found the path blocked with a rock. The game says it can be moved, but it doesn't say how. How do I move a rock in Pokemon Uranium?

Apparently there is nothing about it on the web and no documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move rocks you need the HM move Strength learned on a Pokemon currently in your party. According to the TM/HM locations list on the [wiki for Uranium](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_TM_and_HM_locations), the HM Strength is in the game (located in Legen Town) and I wouldn't expect it's functionality to have changed from the official games.

Comment: That's my first pokemon game I'm playing, so I don't know how things work and the nomenclatures... I will search for that HM Strength at Legen Town. Thank you!

Comment: @vianna77 Welcome to the world of Pokemon! It just goes to show how much knowledge some of us long-time players take for granted, like in this situation haha :). A HM (or 'Hidden Machine') is an item you use to teach a Pokemon a move - in this case the move 'Strength'. Most HM moves have uses outside of Pokemon battles. Hope you're enjoying the game :)

Comment: It's not exactly "taking for granted" when Red/Blue didn't tell us how rocks could be moved either ;)

Comment: I guess it will complement the answer: I got the Rock Smash HM after defeating Theo in Nowtoch city -> The professor sent me the HM. Per the Wikia description, it seems to be able to move rocks inside caves and paths.